# Redirect HTTPS 443 Port to multiple sites on other servers

Tags: apache, networking, ssl, https

The scenario is this: On side "A" where I stay I can only use 443 for HTTPS from the browser, no other port is enabled for HTTPS requests. In the side "B" I have multiple HTTPS sites in different LAN servers behind one IP address to Internet.

Is a possible way to do something to access the multiple HTTPS Sites from the side "A"?. If I do port forwarding on the side B like: from side A :443 to side B : it works but only for one of the HTTPS sites.

I looked in to installing an Apache Server with SNI (server name indication) to do www.sideb.server1.com:443 and www.sideb.server2.com:443 to the only IP Address on side B and different servers, but don't know if I can "transfer" the traffic from that server to another one. Redirects, I assume, do not work because the client on side A cannot access other ports from side B.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to let apache or ngnix work a a reverse proxy and forward the data to the right host based on the server name the clients sends using SNI. But, in this case all the certificates need to be located at side A, so that the reverse proxy can terminate the SSL connection with the correct certificate. And, client certificates will not work.

In theory there is another option: one could write a kind of proxy, which just looks at the initial SSL Client Hello (e.g the first packet sent from the client), extracts the clear-text server name extension and then forwards the whole connection to the right host. In this case you don't need to have the final certificates at the proxy side because you don't terminate the connection and client certificates will also work. Maybe someone has coded this already.